# Different Where with Multiple Select from correct table through inner join in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have some tables as follows:

- Operator (Id as PK, Name, Phone1, Phone2, Username, Password, RoleId)
- Customer (Id as PK, SubscriptionNumber, Name, Phone1, Phone2, Address)
- Worker (Id as PK, Name, Phone1, Phone2, ProfessionId)

I want to implement a callerId System (When a Caller Called, its information retrieved from corresponding table) so I have this table:

- CallerId (Id as PK, CallingId, CallingTypeId, Phone, CallDateTime)

CallingId refer to Operator.Id or Customer.Id, or Worker.Id

So, there are three FK from CallingId to these three PK.

This function is a snippet of my code to retrieve all callerId information between two dates from these three tables:

```
public List<dynamic> GetByDateTime(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    using (MehrpouyanEntities dbContext = new MehrpouyanEntities())
    {
        var query1 = (from cl in dbContext.CallerIds                                             
            join op in dbContext.Operator on cl.CallingId equals op.Id
            where (cl.CallDateTime >= startDate && cl.CallDateTime <= endDate && CallingTypeId == 1)                             
            select (new {op.Id, SubscriptionNumber=0, op.Name, cl.Phone, op.Address, cl.CallDateTime })).ToList<dynamic>();

        var query2 = (from cl in dbContext.CallerIds                                             
            join wr in dbContext.Customer on cl.CallingId equals cu.Id
            where (cl.CallDateTime >= startDate && cl.CallDateTime <= endDate && CallingTypeId == 2)                             
            select (new {cu.Id, cu.SubscriptionNumber, cu.Name, cl.Phone, cu.Address, cl.CallDateTime })).ToList<dynamic>();

        var query3 = (from cl in dbContext.CallerIds                                             
            join wr in dbContext.Workers on cl.CallingId equals wr.Id
            where (cl.CallDateTime >= startDate && cl.CallDateTime <= endDate && CallingTypeId == 2)                             
            select (new {wr.Id, SubscriptionNumber=0, wr.Name, cl.Phone, wr.Address, cl.CallDateTime })).ToList<dynamic>();

        return query1.Concat(query2).Concat(query3).ToList<dynamic>();
    }
}
```

we assumed:

- for Operators CallingTypeId = 1
- for Customer  CallingTypeId = 2
- for Worker  CallingTypeId = 3

How convert these three query to one?

One more important question: Is this Design for DB Correct?

Comment: Remove `ToList` calls from query 1, 2, 3 and after `Concat`s you'll get a single `UNION ALL` SQL query.

Comment: Note that I have different where and different select, How can I do that?

Comment: Keep them as they are. Just remove `ToList<dynamic>()` at the end of `query1`, `query2` and `query3`. I guess you know that the query is not executed if you don't call `ToList` or similar.

Comment: Maybe Operator, Customer and Worker should inherit from CallerId entity. Then you can query to CallerId DbSet (EF internally query to each "child" table. It depends on your strategy). See [Inheritance Strategy in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Stoev , What is your idea about my important question: Is this Design for DB Correct?

Comment: Well, the relationship in question cannot be mapped automatically with EF because it cannot be expressed with db FK constraint. By the same reason you cannot enforce the `CallingId` being one of the desired tables `Id` in the database and cannot control what happens when some of the records in the referenced tables are deleted. Probably a better design would be to let `Operator`, `Customer` and `Worker` inherit some common base abstract class and shared table using EF inheritance as per @JoseAlonsoMonge's comment.